# How to emit multiple actions in one epic using redux-observable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm new to rxjs/redux observable and want to do two things:

1) improve this epic to be more idiomatic

2) dispatch two actions from a single epic

Most of the examples I see assume that the api library will throw an exception when a fetch fails, but i've designed mine to be a bit more predictable, and with Typescript union types I'm forced to check an `ok: boolean` value before I can unpack the results, so understanding how to do this in rxjs has been a bit more challenging.

What's the best way to improve the following? If the request is successful, I'd like to emit both a success action (meaning the user is authorized) and also a 'fetch account' action, which is a separate action because there may be times where I need to fetch the account outside of just 'logging in'. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const authorizeEpic: Epic<ActionTypes, ActionTypes, RootState> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.attemptLogin.request)),
    switchMap(async val => {
      if (!val.payload) {
        try {
          const token: Auth.Token = JSON.parse(
            localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY) || ""
          );
          if (!token) {
            throw new Error();
          }
          return actions.attemptLogin.success({
            token
          });
        } catch (e) {
          return actions.attemptLogin.failure({
            error: {
              title: "Unable to decode JWT"
            }
          });
        }
      }

      const resp = await Auth.passwordGrant(
        {
          email: val.payload.email,
          password: val.payload.password,
          totp_passcode: ""
        },
        {
          url: "localhost:8088",
          noVersion: true,
          useHttp: true
        }
      );

      if (resp.ok) {
        return [
          actions.attemptLogin.success({
            token: resp.value
          })
          // EMIT action 2, etc...
        ];
      }

      return actions.attemptLogin.failure(resp);
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for `switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) indicate the project function (the lambda in your example) may return the following:

```
type ObservableInput<T> = SubscribableOrPromise<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T>
```

When a `Promise<T>` is returned, the resolved value is simply emitted. In your example, if you return an array from your `async` scope, the *array* will be sent directly to the Redux store. Assuming you have no special Redux middlewares setup to handle an array of events, this is likely not what you want. Instead, I would recommend returning an observable in the project function. It's a slight modification to your example:

```js
const authorizeEpic: Epic<ActionTypes, ActionTypes, RootState> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.attemptLogin.request)), // or `ofType` from 'redux-observable'?
    switchMap(action => {
      if (action.payload) {
        try {
          const token: Auth.Token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY) || "")
          if (!token) {
            throw new Error()
          }

          // return an observable that emits a single action...
          return of(actions.attemptLogin.success({
            token
          }))
        } catch (e) {
          // return an observable that emits a single action...
          return of(actions.attemptLogin.failure({
            error: {
              title: "Unable to decode JWT"
            }
          }))
        }
      }

      // return an observable that eventually emits one or more actions...
      return from(Auth.passwordGrant(
        {
          email: val.payload.email,
          password: val.payload.password,
          totp_passcode: ""
        },
        {
          url: "localhost:8088",
          noVersion: true,
          useHttp: true
        }
      )).pipe(
        mergeMap(response => response.ok
          ? of(
            actions.attemptLogin.success({ token: resp.value }),
            // action 2, etc...
          )
          : of(actions.attemptLogin.failure(resp))
        ),
      )
    }),
  )
```

I don't have your TypeScript type definitions, so I can't verify the example above works exactly. However, I've had quite good success with the more recent versions of TypeScript, RxJS, and redux-observable. Nothing stands out in the above that makes me think you should encounter any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip your actions and return them.

```
zip(actions.attemptLogin.success({
            token: resp.value
          })
          // EMIT action 2, etc...
```

So that, now both your actions will be called.

Comment: I tried that, was getting a typescript error, and when running get the " Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions." error.

Comment: The "Actions must be plain objects" is likely due to an _array_ being emitted from the epic and sent to the Redux store. Without custom middleware, Redux simply won't accept the array.